# Kubuntu 20.04: how to force my Bluetooth headset unit profile to HSP/HFP?

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

Since I upgraded to Kubuntu 20.04 I have the following problem: when I connect my USB headset, it's automatically configured in A2DP profile, while I need to use it in HSP/HFP profile in order to make phone calls.
The automatic switching from A2DP to HSP/HFP profile does not work with the program I'm using, neither with the default option `auto_switch=1` of `module-bluetooth-policy`, nor with `auto_switch=2`: the main problem is that the program I use, which is *Linphone*, needs the audio sinks be present on startup, before audio even starts, in order to make them selectable for input and output in the application settings. Therefore, I have to change the headset profile in the audio system settings from A2DP to HSP/HFP whenever I turn it on and before starting *Linphone*.

So, after deep investigation (there are many similar questions described here and on other sites) I ended up with the following command:

```
pactl set-card-profile <my_card_name> headset_head_unit
```

which works when run from the command line. However, when I add it to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` like this:

```
.ifexists <my_card_name>
pactl set-card-profile <my_card_name> headset_head_unit
.endif
```

it does not work, probably because that file is parsed and run on PulseAudio server startup, which is too early. So, I would need to execute that command as soon as the headset is plugged in. Probably a UDEV rule is needed, but it's beyond my skills.

Or, some way to change the profile priority in PulseAudio would also make the trick without any UDEV rule; `pactl list` shows (translating from Italian):

```
Card #3
        Name: <my_card_name>
        Driver: module-bluez5-device.c
        Owning module: 24
        Properties:
                device.description = "Mpow M5"
                device.string = "<MAC address>"
                device.api = "bluez"
                device.class = "sound"
                device.bus = "bluetooth"
                device.form_factor = "headset"
                bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_<MAC address>"
                bluez.class = "0x240404"
                bluez.alias = "Mpow M5"
                device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
                device.intended_roles = "phone"
        Profiles:
                headset_head_unit: Headset head unit (HSP/HFP) (sink: 1, sources: 1, priority: 30, available: yes)
                a2dp_sink: High-fidelity playback (sink A2DP) (sink: 1, sources: 0, priority: 40, available: yes)
                off: Off (sink: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        Active profile: headset_head_unit
        Ports:
                headset-output: Headphones with microphone (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
                        Profiles: headset_head_unit, a2dp_sink
                headset-input: Headphones with microphone (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
                        Profiles: headset_head_unit
```

Perhaps, if I could change that `priority: 30` to (say) `priority: 50`, I could tell PulseAudio to prefer HSP/HFP profile over A2DP. However, I could not find any hint on PulseAudio documentation or on the net on how to change that value.

Comment: For reasons outside the scope of this question, the automatic switching from A2DP to HSP/HFP profile does not work with the program I'm using     Are you sure that info will not help find you an answer?

Comment: @David Indeed, I wrote the reason for which the automatic switching does not work. I need the headset to be configured with HSP/HFP profile BEFORE Linphone starts. After all, it's quite frustrating I can't tell the system to use my headset as a headset. I have no interest at all in A2DP for this unit, it's just a mono headphone with a mic, useful for telephony applications, not to listen to music (which sounds horrible in any case).